# Page becomes slow after adding some points at an interval

Tags: openlayers

I have an interval that sends request to the server every 2 seconds and updates the map data.

The server sends json and in Javascript i iterate over and set some styles and features. However i noticed that the page becomes very slow after a while. Probably something has to be reseted, each time i call the `posgres` function.

See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n26s3ha8/1/)

```
   function Posgres(data){
    function iconStyle(iconSrc) {
        return new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                src: iconSrc
            })
        })
    }
    data.DEVICES.forEach(feature => {
        let popupData = p(feature)
        let iconName = feature.ICON
        let iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point([Number(feature.longitude), Number(feature.latitude)]).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
            name: `<b>Name:</b>` + feature.name + `<br>` + popupData + `<br><b>Received at:</b>` + feature.received_at
        })
        iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle(iconName))
        vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature)
    })
}
function sendRequest() {
    $.post("MapMarkers.php", null, null, "json")
        .done(data => {
            Posgres(data)
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("error loading data")
        })

       var element = document.getElementById('popup')

    var popup = new ol.Overlay({
        element: element,
        positioning: 'bottom-center',
        stopEvent: false,
        offset: [0, -15]
    })
    map.addOverlay(popup)
}


sendRequest()

setInterval(() => {
    sendRequest()
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Please include relevant part of your code in the body of the question.

Comment: I added some of the code but i encourage you to read the fiddle. See how `posgres` function is called

Comment: How many devices are we talking about here? And how many are pulled per call, on average?

Comment: @ThingumaBob Just 4 devices. All of them are sent as json per call

Comment: ah, sorry, I tried to find out how many *locations* those devices sendd; how many features are added per call? only like one or two (if even, considering the interval)?

Comment: 1 feature per device.

Comment: Where's Mike!! :)

Comment: The problem is that you are adding new features every two seconds (4 if I understood what you said above), instead what you want is to add those features initially, and then only update their geometry in later calls to "MapMarkers.php".
What I'd suggest is that you assign them an id (feature.setId(id)) in your initial call, and then retrieve these features in later calls of your script with the "getFeatureById" method on your vector source (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#getFeatureById)

Comment: You are also adding an overlay every two seconds .. I'd suggest you take this out of your "sendRequests" function

Comment: @Alexis_A your comments helped. Also i need to update the icon without setting the style again. I tried `feature_.style_.image_.iconImage_.src_ = device.ICON ` . ~  device.ICON is the icon name that comes from the server.

Comment: You can instead call `getStyle()` on the feature, then use `setImage()` on the returned style from `getStyle`.
OpenLayers have builtin methods for pretty much everything, you shouldn't access the object properties directly. Have a look at the documentation : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/

Comment: I don't know if the page will become slow again if i keep the `setstyle`.